# Xcode Non public API

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, swiftui

When I upload a test build using the default `SwiftUI` project and nothing else, just as it begins negotiating `API` with `iTunes` Connect, the upload terminates with error that build is using `non-public` API along with a seemingly endless stream of `SwiftUI` error details. Makes no sense since the project is only using Apple default project for `SwiftUI`.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: isn't it SwiftUI is still in beta?

Comment: It's been my experience that late August or early September Apple will send out an announcement that you can start uploading your Xcode 11 app to App Store Connect. For now, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Apple usually only allows you to use a GM version of XCode to compile apps for the App Store. You cannot use a beta version of Xcode. Xcode 11 is still (as of this question) in beta.